# How can I display a string as a combination of password chars and original form in asp.net Textbox control ?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Textbox control in which user can add/edit/delete values through this control.It only allows 10 digit numeric value. The first 5 digits should be shown as password chars and last 5 digit should be shown as its original form. (Eg: The value 1234567890 should be shown as *****67890).

How can I implement this in asp.net Textbox control?

Comment: why you want like that functionality? And there's no functionality in C# for textboxes to club both password and normal values.

Comment: They want the functionality because business sometimes demand weird and wonderful things.

Comment: Why don't you simply use a normal TextBox and manipulate the string accordingly, so that the first 5 digits are * and the rest is clear text? For example: `string password="MyPassWord"; TxtPwd.Text="*****" + password.Substring(5);`

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I completely agree with you! Hope there is no requirement to extract the actual value from the text box after that.

Comment: @Ranhiru: Yes, i wouldn't use a TextBox at all for this requirement but a Label. And if user needs to change the password he could provide a normal TextBox in [TextMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textmode.aspx) password.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps make two textboxes that appear close together. Even given the first box behaviour that when the first 5 characters are filled, that the focus is given to the seonc box.

Another way is to have one textbox and one hidden box. As the characters are typed, they go into the hidden. The hidden is rendered to the textbox where after the first 5 characters, you replace any other characters with *

Answer (score 1):

Separate out the two textboxes like so and then combine the two (possibly into a composite control) exposing the concatenated value of the two textboxes as a property.

**Markup**

```
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="passwordPortionTextBox" runat="server" TextMode="Password" MaxLength="5"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="normalPortionTextBox" runat="server" MaxLength="5"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$(function () {

    $('#<%= passwordPortionTextBox.ClientID %>').keypress(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length == 4) {
            $('#<%= normalPortionTextBox.ClientID %>').focus();
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot implement this in a single control. Use two text box controls (side-by-side) and set one as a password field and the other as a plain text field. And of course, set max length to 5 on both.

Answer (score 0):

I think this behavior is very specific, maybe the best approach would be to create your own Textbox which derives from the asp.net Textbox Control and then add your functionality to it.

That's not so easy. :D  Maybe you could work with Client side code too and look for the text changed or key stoke and change the characters to password characters, but then you have to store somewhere the original string too.

I'm not really an expert on ASP.NET but i hope my answer helps you a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

To make a text box in C# display only the first 5 and last characters as asterisks (similar to a password field), you can handle the TextChanged event of the text box and update the text as follows:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
if (textBox1.Text.Length > 5)
{
    string maskedText = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, 5) + new string('*', textBox1.Text.Length - 10) + textBox1.Text.Substring(textBox1.Text.Length - 5);
    textBox1.Text = maskedText;
    textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
}
```

}

In the code above, we first check if the length of the text box's text is greater than 5. If it is, we create a new string called maskedText which contains the first 5 characters of the text box's text, followed by a number of asterisks equal to the length of the text minus 10, and then the last 5 characters of the text. We then set the text of the text box to the maskedText string and set the SelectionStart property to the end of the text box, so that the cursor stays at the end of the masked text.